# Access PrismaClient instance in multiple files

Tags: javascript, express, prisma

I have a node.js/express app with the Prisma ORM. I would like to access my PrismaClient instance in multiple files, not just index.ts.

Tutorials I have seen all only access the PrismaClient instance inside index.ts, which makes that file bloated.

For example, I have folders for routes and controllers. I would like to access the PrismaClient in each of the files within the controllers folder.

Current code:

index.ts

```js
    import express from "express"; 
    import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
    import userRoutes from "./routes/users";
    
    
    const app = express(); 
    
    // best not to have multiple instances of PrismaClient
    export const prisma = new PrismaClient();
    
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.send("helloBAA")
    })
    
    // routes 
    app.use('/api/users', userRoutes)
    
    app.listen(3500, () => {
        console.log("listening on port 3500")
    })
```

routes/users.ts

```js
    import { Router } from 'express'; 
    import { createUser, getUsers, getUser } from '../controllers/users';
    const router = Router(); 
    
    
    // whole route: /api/users...
    router.post('/create', createUser); 
    router.get('/all', getUsers);
    router.get('/:userId', getUser); 
    
    
    export default router;
```

controllers/users.ts

```js
    import { RequestHandler } from 'express'; 
    // import prisma from './index.ts';
    import dotenv  from "dotenv"
    import axios from 'axios'; 
    
    
    export const createUser:RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
      let newObj = {
          username: req.body.username,
          email: req.body.email, 
          password: req.body.password
        }   
      
        res.status(200).json({ "test": "createUser" });
    }
    
    export const getUsers: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
    
      res.status(200).json({ "test": "getUsers" });
    }
    
    export const getUser: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
    
      res.status(200).json({ "test": "getUser" });
    }
```

If I try to import prisma from index.ts into controllers/users.ts, I get errors. How should I fix this?

Comment: Create a const instance in another file

Comment: I have a const instance in index.ts that I am exporting already. Is the problem just that it is coming from index.ts?

Comment: already have "export const prisma = new PrismaClient();" in index.ts

Comment: Move it to another file to avoid circular dependencies

Answer (score 2):

This is because circular dependency where two or more modules depend on each other directly or indirectly, froming a loop.
Make the prismaClient instance in a separate file and import this whenever required.Like this:I have a prismaClient.ts file

```
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");
const prismaInstance = new PrismaClient();

module.exports = prisma;
```

import the file in the index.ts like this:

```
const prismaInstance = require("./prismaClient");
export const prisma = prismaInstance;
```

Import the file from index.ts to required files:

```
const prisma = require('./index');
```